Update AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp without restarting application
I have used AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp in my program.cs class for Microsoft Authentication.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(opts =>
{
    var azureOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureAppOptions>>().CurrentValue;

    opts.Instance = azureOptions.Instance;
    opts.TenantId = azureOptions.TenantId;
    opts.ClientId = azureOptions.ClientId;
    opts.CallbackPath = azureOptions.CallbackPath;
}, openIdConnectScheme: OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

If I have to update Azure App details then, I have to restart my application because AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp only runs at start up.
Is it possible to modify AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp so that it start using new app details without restarting the application.
